# Is there a problem of designing the grid view in CSS

Tags: html, css

Getting not balance grid view design. Trying to design a row of grid view but the first one is off. The first one and the second, third using different style but tried modified but it still not working.

https://codepen.io/levi88888/pen/wvWomNB

[image]

```
           <div class="view_wrap template-grid-view">
                   <div class="template-view_item">
                     <div class="template-add-item">
                      Content
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 
                      <div class="template-view_item">
                        <div class="template-vi_left">
                         template content
                        </div>
                        <div class="template-vi_right">
                          <strong class="d-block">template name</strong>
                          <small class="content">Edited at date time</small>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: If you apply `display:table`, it pushes the one on the left into position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting your

```
<div class="view_wrap template-grid-view">
```

as a flex container by typing this in your CSS file:

```
    .template-grid-view{
    display: flex;
    }
```

More information on how to use flexboxes can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).